# Why do we assume a distribution for the dependent variable and not the error when using GLMs?

Tags: regression, logistic, multiple-regression, generalized-linear-model, econometrics

OLS: $y = X\beta+ \epsilon$ with $\epsilon \sim N(0,\sigma^2)$

GLM: $g(\mu) = X\beta$ with $y \sim $<Distribution from exponential family>

I have knowledge of OLS and am trying to understand the more general case of GLM. I noticed that for GLMs the assumption of the distribution is made on $y$ and $\epsilon$ is never explicitly shown in any of the equations. I am aware that in OLS the assumption $\epsilon \sim N(0,\sigma^2)$ implies $y \sim N(X\beta,\sigma^2I)$, but I want to know:

1. Why do we not explicitly show $\epsilon$ in the GLM model (or probit & logit)?
2. Is $\epsilon$ even present in these models? The model is not perfect and therefore there has to be an error, but where exactly is it? Can you write the GLM model with $\epsilon$ so I can see how it is incorporated in the model?

Answer (score 1):

> 1. Why do we not explicitly show $\epsilon$ in the GLM model (or probit & logit)?

It can surely be shown, but does not lead to any new insight. For example, for the Bernoulli GLM model, we have an assumption on the $y$, that it is Bernoulli-distributed. The residuals, however, are not (since they are continuous) and should have a more complicated distribution.

> 2. Is $\epsilon$ even present in these models? The model is not perfect and therefore there has to be an error, but where exactly is it? Can you write the GLM model with $\epsilon$ so I can see how it is incorporated in the model?

If $E(y|X) = \mu = g^{-1}(\eta)$, where $\eta = \beta X$, then $y_i = \hat{\mu_i} + \epsilon_i$.

Comment: But in $y = \hat{\mu} + \epsilon$ you claim that the observation $y_i$ equals the mean (or technically an estimator of the mean) plus an error. Shouldn't it be the case that $E(y) = \hat{\mu} + E(\epsilon)$ but then again $E(\epsilon)=0$ and we no longer show $\epsilon)$ explicitly in the equations?

Comment: @Xtiaan Why would you do the expected value of $y$?

Comment: Because according to the current equation we say that y equals the the predictor of the mean of y (+ an error). Should it not be the case that we say that y equals a predictor of y (+ an error) or that the expectation of y equals a the predictor of the mean of y (+ an error)?

Comment: @Xtiaan the predictor and the conditional expectation are the same thing.

Comment: So $y_i = \hat{\mu_i} + \epsilon_i$ says that its observation equals $E(y_i)$ plus an error. However, what is $E(y_i)$? Isn't $y_i$ just an observation. Isn't $y$ stochastic and not $y_i$?